# Excel Pivot Table : Calculated Field ( formula to be used like sumproduct)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

[image]

As shown in image i have source data. ( Column A to D)

I want to generate pivot table without inserting any new column in source data.
My final goal is to get Pivot Table to display totals "By country" then "By Product" ( as shown manually green section)

I tried several ways my final out come is Pink color pivot table ... which is showing incorrect value. I have added calculated filed to arrive results but calculated filed is now showing incorrect numbers.

Can anyone help me to get correct numbers in pivot table....
Green color pivot table is manually created. ( expected output)

File can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/b86wdaj5803plgh/ExcelPivotQuery.xlsx?dl=0

[Source Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b86wdaj5803plgh/ExcelPivotQuery.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that with a `Calculated Field`, as it will take the *product of the sums* as opposed to the *sums of the products*. For example, for `Egypt|Prod_1`, you are expecting:

`(2,325*86)+(4,245*78)=199,950+331,110=531,060`

but rather the `Calculated Field` is performing:

`(2,325+4,245)*(86+78)=6,570*164=1,077,480`

I would add your table to the `Data Model` and then use a `Measure`:

`=SUMX(MyTable,MyTable[Quantity]*MyTable[Unit Price])`

changing the table name as required.